# Does sampling a distribution linearly at random preserve that distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a set of values, S, that have a gaussian distribution.

I order the set in some way, assigning an integer "position" to each value in S.

I then sample the set S, by choosing values based on a position linearly at random (so the distribution of my position sampling is linear). My sampled values form a new set, Q.

Do the values in the new set, Q, also have a gaussian distribution? Do the relative sizes of the sets Q and S affect this? Does the order I choose to assign integer "positions" to values in S prior to sampling affect this?

I am not sure what concepts from mathematics this even deals with, beyond "stats". I am working with generating synthetic data, and I want to manipulate sets of values while preserving underlying statistical properties (in this case distributions). What should I search for to learn more about this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X \sim N_q(\mu, \Sigma)$ is a $q$ dimensional Gaussian vector. Let $M \in \{0, 1\}^{r \times q}$ be a random matrix where

1. $r < q$ and
2. $M \mathbf{1}_q = \mathbf{1}_r$

(1) and (2) basically formulates what it means to subsample a vector, as $M X \in \mathbb{R}^r$ is a subvector of randomly selected elements of $X$. If we were to just inspect the first element,
\begin{align*}
(MX)_1 = m_{11}X_1 + \cdots + m_{1q}X_q
\end{align*}
In the simplest setting where we perform simple random sampling, the vector $(m_{11}, \cdots, m_{1q})$ follows a categorical distribution with probabilities $1/q$ for each element. This form reveals that $(MX)_1$ is the Gaussian mixture distribution $\frac{1}{q}N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2) + \cdots + \frac{1}{q}N(\mu_q, \sigma_q^2)$, which is not Gaussian. Since one element of the vector is not Gaussian, the entire vector $(MX)_1$ cannot be multivariate Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

I would search for the keyword "bootstrap" which is any kind of sampling with replacement to enlarge a dataset. In general I think it preserves the distribution if S and Q are large enough. See a picture of a mixture Gaussian distribution of 9,900 data points on the left and a sample in the middle of size 5000 without replacement, and a bootstrapped sample of size 10,000 on the right with replacement.

[image]